# Is there any way to produce a random Voronoi diagram with a specific length and width?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, tessellations, voronoi-diagram

A Voronoi diagram is an approach to the tessellation of medium. In this diagram, there are many points in a plane that divide the medium to many specific regions by their bisector. Any region is convex and has a circumscribed rectangle. the circumscribed rectangle of convex shape that has the smallest area (We have an algorithm to imagine any edge on the direction of a specific edge and perpendicular to edge and find a rectangle with the smallest area.). I want to place the points in a way that creat random convex polygons (Random means have different numbers of edges.). But I want to control the size of the width and length of their circumscribed rectangle. So I want to know is there any algorithm (as math or computer) for the locating points with the above property?
[Voronoi tessellation with known cell areas and unknown seeds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554742/voronoi-tessellation-with-known-cell-areas-and-unknown-seeds?rq=1)
Same class solution and there are still some people that say "Please clarify".
I don't edit the question. You can close the question. I will go and find the answer and come back and write it here.

Comment: What exactly do you call a circumscribed rectangle ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust For any convex shape, there is a rectangle with the shortest width and longest length. I mean the circumscribed rectangle of convex shape that has the smallest area.

Comment: "Smallest area" is ok. "Shortest width *and* longest length" is not necessarily possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think both are the same. We have an algorithm to imagine any edge on the direction of a specific edge and perpendicular to edge and find a rectangle with smallest area.

Comment: No, they are not the same. There is no bounding rectangle with "shortest width and longest length" that circumscribes a square.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  OK. Circumscribed rectangle has a specific length and width. These variables are specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109677/discussion-between-alin-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: Learn punctuation, grammar, and other writing skills before making ill-informed guesses about other people's knowledge of English. Rudeness doesn't help. What might help is if you show an example of a Voronoi diagram that satisfies your conditions.

Comment: @DavidK beautiful "ill-informed"!!! I don't know the mean of "example" (and really if there is an example I don't ask). I just want to tesselate the plane with polygons that have a random number of edges and can control the polygons by the size of their circumscribed rectangle.

Comment: Your examples don't have to be correctly calculated, they just need to illustrate what you mean by what you're trying to say. "I mean something like this: ... but not like this: ... ."

Comment: @DavidK <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#/media/File:Euclidean_Voronoi_diagram.svg"> This is an example of regular random Voronoi diagram. Here We don't have any control over the size (that I described above) of the shapes. I want to locate the point of sites in a way that can control the size of polygons. For example, I can say the size of the site that on (x,y) is W and L.

Comment: I don’t see anything labeled W, L, x, or y in that figure. I think you will have to draw your own figure or at least modify one to show what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Five points arranged in a cross define an arbitrary rectangular Voronoi cell.

[image]

Then you can modify the shape without modifying the bounding rectangle by adding well-chosen points.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly not I want. I want to locate points in space in a way that creat polygon that has a circumscribed rectangle with smallest area. That rectangle has a specific long edge (length) and short edge (width).

Comment: @ALIN: in what way does my solution not allow specific side lengths ??

Comment: I want to tesselate plane with random polygons. These polygons have a circumscribed rectangle with the smallest area. That rectangle has a specific long edge (length) and short edge (width). So at first, there is no one region, second, this shape must random, and third, specific circumscribed rectangle.

Comment: @ALIN: what do you call random ?

Comment: @ALIN: "there is no one region": what ?

Comment: Random means have different numbers of edges. But I want to control the size of the width and length. the region I mean there is no one shapes but we have many shapes.

Comment: man this is wrong solution your solution is just OK for the first shape if we go beyond that one the process is very difficult.

Comment: @ALIN: I regret to have tried to help you.

Comment: Completely clear